# Why did Marty blow up the amplifier in Doc's place?

Tags: back-to-the-future

Why did he blow up that amplifier? There was no point in doing such anything..... Just **curious**...

Comment: Because he wanted to crank it to 11, but it only went to 10.

Comment: yes.. ive got the answer actually.. it was because the amplifier had a problem like overload problems.. im kinda new here

Comment: @anaranjada was making a reference to "This Is Spinal Tap", where they have an amplifier marked from zero [up to eleven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Up_to_eleven). :)

Answer (score 14):

He didn't do it on purpose. After it blows up, there's a conversation with Doc on the phone:

> **Marty McFly**: You know, Doc, you left your equipment on all week.
>
> **Dr. Emmett Brown**: My equipment. That reminds me, Marty. You better not hook up to the amplifier. There's a slight possibility of overload.
>
> **Marty McFly**: Yeah, I'll keep that in mind.

Oopsie! Too late.

Comment: ...and that accident foreshadows the alternately casual & uptight relationship Doc has with the consequences of his work, which - spoiler - plays into the rest of the movie.